# jquery slidetoggle not working properly the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So for my slidetoggle function in jquery, when the website runs, I am trying to originally hide my socials from showing up under Contact. When I click contact, what I want to happen is for the socials to slide down underneath the navigation menu (preferrably to the right of the contact button, if anyone knows how to do this I would be greatly appreciated, otherwise it's fine for now). The first time I click contact, the socials show, but jquery is sliding them up. The function works fine afterwards, but I am trying to figure out how to make it scroll down the first time rather than scroll up, with the toggle function still in effect afterwards. I'm still new to jquery, so help would be appreciated.

Here's my code (jquery is below the html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>RE</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <!--UTF = Universal Character Set + Transformation Format. This encodes every character with the ASCII format (EX: 'A' = 65, 'B' = 66, etc.). Encoding is variable length, and uses 8-bit code units.-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One' rel='stylesheet'>
      <!--First link: Links to CSS file. Second link: Links to a font type unique to Google Fonts.-->
      <script src='main.js'></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas class="img" id="myCanvas" width="70" height="50" style="border:2px solid #d3d3d3;">
         Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
      <!--This canvas tag displays the logo at the top left, and it allows us to design the size and the borders to the logo.-->
      <script>
         var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
         ctx.font = "30px Helvetica";
         ctx.fillText("R E ",9,35);
         var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      </script>
      <!--This script allows us to design the inner portion of the logo at the top left.-->
      <nav>
         <div style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
         <!--Width, margin-left, and margin-right are necessary as it centers the Navigation menu.-->
            <ul>
               <p><a href='index.html'>Home</a> / 
                  <a href='About.html'>About</a> / 
                  <a href='Work.html'>Projects</a> /
                  <a id="contact" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
                  <div class=social1>
                  <p id="slide">
                  <a class="socials" href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" style="width:60px;height:60px;border:0">
                  </a>
                  <a class="socials" href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" style="width:60px;height:60px;border:0">
                  </a>
                  <a class="socials" href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <img src="github.png" alt="Github" style="width:60px;height:60px;border:0">
                  </a>
                  <a class="socials" href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <img src="LinkedIn.png" alt="LinkedIn" style="width:60px;height:60px;border:0">
                  </a>
                  </p>
               </div>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>


   <hr>

</body>
</html>




JQUERY:

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".socials").hide();
            $("#contact").click(function() {
               $(".socials").show();
               $("#slide").slideToggle("slow");
         });      
      });
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm new here and I'm just trying to get help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your css codes and images.

Comment: Sorry about that. Made a jsfiddle page for it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ku0e7drf/1/ Just click the contact button.

Comment: no need to work with `.social` class. When document start, use `hide()` on the `#slide`, then when click to open, just use `$("#slide").slideToggle("slow")`.
https://jsfiddle.net/tc7k069v/

Comment: Also, you don't need to call `$("#slide").hide()` at the beginning, you can just set display none in the CSS, then the `.slideToggle()` will do its work as expected too.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'll also do display none in CSS and try it out from there.

Comment: I have another issue where when I hover over one of the social links, they all shift to the left. How would I make it so when I hover over the links they would stay still?